# Ansible Cloudformation, how to not break if Resource already exists?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I have the following AWS Cloudformation config, which sets up S3, Repositories.

When I run it via an ansible playbook, on the second time running the playbook this happens

```
AWS::ECR::Repository Repository CREATE_FAILED: production-app-name already exists
etc
```

How can I make it so that when this is ran multiple times, it will keep the existing s3 and repository instead of just blowing up? (I had assumed the param `"DeletionPolicy": "Retain",` would do this)

What I'd like to achieve:

If i run this 100x, I want the same resource state as it was after run #1. I do not want any resources deleted/wiped of any data.

```
{


 "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
  "Description": "Pre-reqs for Elastic Beanstalk application",
  "Parameters": {
    "BucketName": {
      "Type": "String",
      "Description": "S3 Bucket name"
    },
    "RepositoryName": {
      "Type": "String",
      "Description": "ECR Repository name"
    }
  },
  "Resources": {
    "Bucket": {
      "Type": "AWS::S3::Bucket",
      "DeletionPolicy": "Retain",
      "Properties": {
        "BucketName": { "Fn::Join": [ "-", [
          { "Ref": "BucketName" },
          { "Ref": "AWS::Region" }
        ]]}
      }
    },
    "Repository": {
      "Type": "AWS::ECR::Repository",
      "DeletionPolicy": "Retain",
      "Properties": {
        "RepositoryName": { "Ref": "RepositoryName" }
      }
    }
  },
  "Outputs": {
    "S3Bucket": {
      "Description": "Full S3 Bucket name",
      "Value": { "Ref": "Bucket" }
    },
    "Repository": {
      "Description": "ECR Repo",
      "Value": { "Fn::Join": [ "/", [
        {
          "Fn::Join": [ ".", [
            { "Ref": "AWS::AccountId" },
            "dkr",
            "ecr",
            { "Ref": "AWS::Region" },
            "amazonaws.com"
          ]]
        },
        { "Ref": "Repository" }
      ]]}
    }
  }
}
```

edit:

DB with similar issue when ran twice

```
{
    "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
    "Parameters": {
        "DBPassword": {
            "MinLength": "8",
            "NoEcho": true,
            "Type": "String"
        },
        "Environment": {
            "MinLength": "1",
            "Type": "String"
        },
        "DBName": {
            "Type": "String",
            "Description": "DBName"
        },
        "DBInstanceIdentifier": {
            "Type": "String",
            "Description": "DBInstanceIdentifier"
        },
        "DBPort": {
            "Type": "String",
            "Description": "DBPort"
        },
        "DBUsername": {
            "Type": "String",
            "Description": "DBName"
        }
    },
    "Outputs": {
        "Url": {
            "Value": {
                "Fn::Sub": "postgres://${DBUsername}:${DBPassword}@${Instance.Endpoint.Address}:${Instance.Endpoint.Port}/${DBName}"
            }
        }
    },
    "Resources": {
        "Instance": {
            "Type": "AWS::RDS::DBInstance",
            "DeletionPolicy": "Retain",
            "Properties": {
                "AllocatedStorage": "10",
                "DBInstanceClass": "db.t2.micro",
                "DBInstanceIdentifier": {"Ref": "DBInstanceIdentifier"},
                "DBName": {
                    "Ref": "DBName"
                },
                "Engine": "postgres",
                "EngineVersion": "9.6.6",
                "MasterUsername": {
                    "Ref": "DBUsername"
                },
                "MasterUserPassword": {
                    "Ref": "DBPassword"
                },
                "MultiAZ": "false",
                "Port": {
                    "Ref": "DBPort"
                },
                "PubliclyAccessible": "false",
                "StorageType": "gp2"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The field `RepositoryName` in `AWS::ECR::Repository` is actually not required and I would advise against specifying one. By letting *CloudFormation* dynamically assign a unique name to the repository you'll avoid collision.

If you later want to use the repository name, for exemple: in a task definition, you can use the `"Ref"` function like so `{ "Ref": "Repository" }` to extract the unique name generated by *CloudFormation*.

As for the issue with the *RDS instance*, tt comes down to the same problem of hardcoding resources name.

Using `retain` will keep the resource alive but it will no longer be managed by *CloudFormation* which is a big problem.

Just make sure when doing updates to never modify a parameter that require a resource "replacement". The documentation always states what kind of update a parameter change will incur.

[image]
Image taken from ([here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-rds-database-instance.html#cfn-rds-dbinstance-port))

If you really need to change a parameter that requires a replacement. Create a new resource with the adapter parameters, migrate whatever data you had in the database or *ECR repository*, then remove the old resource from the template. If you don't need to migrate anything, make sure you don't have hardcoded names and let *CloudFormation* perform the replacement.

Comment: Hmm ok. I also have a "AWS::RDS::DBInstance" Resource which has this exact same issue though. How should I handle that one? (added config to the orig post above)

Comment: That DB instance was being deleted by default upon each deploy previously, then I added ""DeletionPolicy": "Retain"," now it errors saying it already exists.

Comment: Also to clarify, the above configs are ran upon each deply of the application, so for all those resources I need the data to remain. Wiping production on each deply would not be good.

Comment: I've updated the answer with more details on "replacement" updates. Let me know if you still have questions unanswered.

Comment: OK, so basically i need to seperate out my environment creation code from my deploy code I think then. I just run this once without hardcoded resource names. Then have my deploy code just assume the servers are ready

Comment: This is one way to do it, but it could also be all automated inside *CloudFormation*. As long as your deploy code "update" the stack and doesn't "create" a new one. If you need to create a new stack at each deploy. Just make sure the resources that need "creation" are in a separate template. If those resources needs to access resources information, such as a name, from the database stack you can use `Fn::ImportValue` or the regular input parameters to do so.